# Possible norms of transformed vector with initial length of 1

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, normed-spaces

Assuming we have a vector with dimension 5x1 of unit length and we change its dimensions by using with m x 5 sized matrices. Example:

$$ v= \left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
  v_1\\
  v_2\\
v_3\\
 v_4\\
v_5\\
\end{array}
\right],\qquad A = \left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
  1&2&3&5&3\\
  2&5&6&4&11\\
1&2&7&2&3\\
  4&5&6&2&13\\
6&12&6&2&3\\
\end{array}
\right] $$

What I'm trying to find is while assuming $ \left\lVert v\right\rVert = 1$ , what will be $min \left\lVert Av\right\rVert$ and $max \left\lVert Av\right\rVert$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use SVD to attain the answer. So we have $$\min_{||v||=1}||Av||{=\min_{||v||=1}||UDVv||\\=\min_{||v||=1}||DVv||\\=\min_{||w||=1}||Dw||\\=\min_{w_1^2+\cdots+w_n^2=1}\sqrt{|\lambda_1w_1|^2+\cdots+|\lambda_nw_n|^2}}$$where $\lambda_i$s are the eigenvalues of $A$. So we have$$\min_{||v||=1}||Av||=\min_{i}|\lambda_i|$$similarly $$\max_{||v||=1}||Av||=\max_{i}|\lambda_i|$$